# General Iroh and the spirit world

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

So if general Iroh (Zuko's uncle) lives in the spirit world and then Korra opens the spirit world portals does that mean Iroh can come visit Zuko again, and vice versa?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, yes. We're not given any particular restrictions on what allows the spirits to visit the material world, nor are we given any restrictions (to my knowledge, anyways) on humans visiting the spirit world. So they probably should be able to meet again, yes.

Comment: That's what I figured but it's always nice to ask :) I wish they would have showed that at the end :( I think I may have bawled my eyes out lol. Do you happen to know if there's going to be another avatar coming out?

Comment: TV show - Highly doubtful
Comic book/graphic novel/other - Almost certainly

Comment: Really :) that's awesome ! Have they set a date or made any announcement?

Comment: [The Wiki] (http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Favatar.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FList_of_Avatar_books&ei=OwcLVdSGFofdsAScy4KQBA&usg=AFQjCNE3Zk94wCJ5PX94DxlaImjP5Mcp3A&sig2=zC6EaYs6wvxeh1fIWdwWcg&bvm=bv.88528373,d.cWc_ should be able to help you with that, I don't know any specifics

Comment: @MeganAllmanMiddleton http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/07/10/comic-con-the-legend-of-korra-graphic-novel-series-announced

Comment: "[... No restrictions given] on humans visiting the spirit world" - indeed.  Not only are no restrictions given, it's heavily implied that apart from the skills needed to survive in a place as dangerous as the spirit world can be, there *are* none.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for Iroh to visit Lord Zuko. Iroh meditated into the spirit world from the physical world. If Iroh were to go back to the physical world through the portal, he would be like Aang in Winter Solstice: The Spirit World. Zuko would not be able to see or hear him because a spirit was not his original form.

Comment: Reason for downvote: the question is talking about The Legend of Korra, when Iroh has long been dead. He's in the spirit world because he is a spirit of the dead, not because he's projecting himself with meditation. Thus at the very least, Zuko could enter the spirit world and visit Iroh. There's a certain amount of implication that even with the portals open the spirits of the departed don't visit the world of the living, though.